# imakeidx: How can I hyphenate entries of two consecutive pages?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

So I'm using imakeidx and everything is going pretty well.  By default, the final index delimits page ranges of two or fewer with a comma and three or more with an en-dash.  For example:

> Index entry.......................1, 5, 6, 8–10, 14, 15

I am wondering if there is a simple way to edit this so that page ranges of two or fewer will also be delimited by an en-dash, so the above example would instead come out as:

> Index entry.......................1, 5–6, 8–10, 14–15

My index style is as follows, just in case there's an easy tweak to be made there:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{index_style.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\n\\centering{\\large\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n"
item_0 "\n \\item \\small "
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
item_x1 "}
item_0 "\n \\item \\indexmark{"%
\end{filecontents*}
```

My apologies if there's an easy answer to this that I'm oblivious to.

Comment: `imakeidx` only prepares the input to MakeIndex and allows the index to be output in the first pass.  It's actually MakeIndex that does the sorting and combining.  (But I don't know how to force a two-page span to be formatted with an en-dash rather than two separate pages split with a comma.)

Comment: MakeIndex only applies range formation for three or more consecutive pages.